# Flutter Project, Not receive notifications on IOS Apple Device from (azure notification hub) using APNS

Tags: flutter, azure, push-notification, notifications, azure-notificationhub

- using real device
- the app works on production
- receive the notifications on iOS from different 3rd parties like (freshchat and sendbird) normal
- the key id, team id and token are correct
- we use for request for push contains in the body

  - device id from. https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus
  - get the APNS token from Firebase messaging

---

- notification body form Azure

```
"{\"aps\" : {" +
                                               "\"alert\" : {" +
                                                                "\"title\" : \"" + pushMessageViewModel.MessageTitleEn + "\"," +
                                                               //"\"subtitle\" : \"Five Card Draw\"," +
                                                               "\"body\": \"" + pushMessageViewModel.MessageContentEn +
                                                           "\"}," +
                                               "\"sound\":\"default\"" +
                                           "}," +
                                "\"data\" : {" +
                                                "\"body\":\"" + pushMessageViewModel.MessageContentEn + "\"," +
                                                    "\"title\":\"" + pushMessageViewModel.MessageTitleEn + "\"" + "," +
                                                    "\"code\":\"" + pushMessageViewModel.Code + "\"" + "," +
                                                    "\"alert\":\"" + pushMessageViewModel.Alert + "\"" + "," +
                                                    "\"extra_params\":" + extraParametersStringBuilder.ToString() + "," +
                                                    "\"type\":\"" + pushMessageViewModel.MessageTypeCode + "\"" +
                                            "}" +
                                "}";
```

- `AppDelegate.swift` swift code

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

import UserNotifications
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    
    // Below code is implementation for user interaction listener support
    // FreshchatSdkPluginWindow needs to be initialised in the target application's app delegate for the user interaction listener to work
    // @property (nonatomic, strong) FreshchatSdkPluginWindow *window; should be added in the header file as well
    let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as! UIViewController
    window = FreshchatSdkPluginWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window.rootViewController = viewController
    
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
            print("grant: \(granted)")
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // Register for FCM
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        let freshchatSdkPlugin = FreshchatSdkPlugin()
        print("Device Token \(deviceToken)")
        print("Device token is set")
       freshchatSdkPlugin.setPushRegistrationToken(deviceToken)
    }



    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // Handle FCM messages here
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    
    override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Reset the badge count when the app becomes active
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
    }
    
    

    //@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
            willPresent: UNNotification,
            withCompletionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions)->()) {
        let freshchatSdkPlugin = FreshchatSdkPlugin()
    if freshchatSdkPlugin.isFreshchatNotification(willPresent.request.content.userInfo) {
        freshchatSdkPlugin.handlePushNotification(willPresent.request.content.userInfo) //Handled for freshchat notifications
    } else {
        withCompletionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge]) //For other notifications
         }
    }
    //@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler: @escaping ()->()) {
        let freshchatSdkPlugin = FreshchatSdkPlugin()
    if freshchatSdkPlugin.isFreshchatNotification(didReceive.notification.request.content.userInfo) {
        freshchatSdkPlugin.handlePushNotification(didReceive.notification.request.content.userInfo) //Handled for freshchat notifications
           withCompletionHandler()
    } else {
           withCompletionHandler() //For other notifications
        }
    }
}
```

- we try to change

  - bundle id
  - certificate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Adel, you still have this problem? I have it too and I tried so many things that I found on internet, none work.

Comment: Hi @DouglasGarrido, we didn't solve it. After two weeks with no solution, we changed the implementation of notifications on IOS at Backend to make it work in FCM instead of APNS.